# How do I configure markdownlint for Visual Studo Code differently for CHANGELOG files

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, lint

I like the markdownlint extension for Visual Studio Code, but the default settings do not work well for [changelog](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/) files.

How can I configure markdownlint differently for the CHANGELOG.md file, but use the normal settings for all other markdown files?

In particular, I wish to disable the following for CHANGELOG.md files:

- MD024/no-duplicate-heading

And, stylistically, I'd like to also disable

- MD032/blanks-around-lists
- MD022/blanks-around-headings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this line to the tail of my CHANGELOG.md file, and that worked:

```
<!-- markdownlint-configure-file { "MD022": false, "MD024": false, "MD030": false, "MD032": false} -->
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not see an option to configure markdown lint rules based on file extensions or file names. However, you can add `<!-- markdownlint-disable MD024 -->` to the top of the CHANGELOG.md file to disable this rule for that particular file.

More details can be found at https://github.com/DavidAnson/vscode-markdownlint#configure

Comment: Thanks, Ryan Taylor.  I found a more comprehensive way to do what I wanted, so I went ahead and answered my own question.  I should have remembered to do that once I figured it out. :-/